# Why is this loop selecting multiple cells with the Areas function?

Tags: excel, vba

I have this loop to select the items in a column in a cell by cell basis, and test each against the previous. Every once in a while, maybe 2 to 4 times in 100 loops, Areas. selects two cells, and the code throws an error, type mismatch, since it cannot compare value of 2 cells. Why is this happening?

I have tried to use alternate methods to loop through the cells, and am open to suggestions, but this is the way that I have found has mostly worked since I want to loop through just visible cells.

```
Dim Fchours As Range

Set Fchours = ActiveSheet.Range(rng1.Address).SpecialCells _
        (xlCellTypeVisible)

Do While i < 328
If ActiveSheet.FilterMode = True Then
    Fchours.Areas(i + 1).Select
    If ((Fchours.Areas(i + 1).Value) <> "") Then
        If (Fchours.Areas(i).Value) < 5000 Then
            If ((Fchours.Areas(i + 1).Value) < (Fchours.Areas(i).Value)) Then
            FCcount = FCcount + 1
            End If
        End If
    End If
End If

i = i + 1
Loop
```

I expect it to select individual cells at a time, and most of the time it does, just every now and again it selects 2.

Comment: What line is your error occurring? Also, type mismatch will occur if you are trying to compare two different data types, example `If Long > String Then` or `Long < Boolean Then`.

Comment: Why is two cells in an area impossible?

Comment: It occurs on the second nested if statement, or the 3rd if I skip the second, and two cells isn't impossible, but to use the .Value function and compare them, I can't have two cells selected.

Comment: It is probable that the times when `Areas` refers to multiple cells are times when your filter has resulted in adjacent cells being part of the visible cells. You should first loop through the `Areas` returned by `SpecialCells` and then the cells of the `Area`.

Comment: That was it, Thank you!